# java map dot put not working in a for loop

Tags: java, dictionary, for-loop, generics, jvm

I am new to the Map class and I was wondering what I am doing wrong. Below is the class I am working on to learn Maps.

```
import java.util.*;  
public class Maptester{
  Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  public Maptester(String[] x){
    for(int i = 0; i > x.length; i++) map.put(i, x[i]);
  }
  public Maptester(ArrayList<String> x){
    for(int i = 0; i > x.size(); i++) map.put(i, x.get(i));
  }
  public String toString(){
    String x = "";
    for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()){  
      x += (m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue()+"\n");
    } return x; 
  }
}
```

This is the Main Class I am using.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] x = {"x", "y", "z"};
    Maptester b = new Maptester(x);
    System.out.print(b);
  }
}
```

The output for this is nothing, for some reason nothing is put in map in the for loop at the top and I don't understand why.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i > x.size(); i++)`? Simple debugging would have resolved this almost immediately.

Comment: Yea check your loops. > vs < makes a big difference. Also check better way to iterate maps. https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-loop-a-map-in-java/

Comment: `Map.Entry` should be parameterized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the wrong predicate in the for loop. This will do the job:

```
public class Maptester{
  Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  public Maptester(String[] x){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) map.put(i, x[i]);
  }
  public Maptester(ArrayList<String> x){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) map.put(i, x.get(i));
  }
  public String toString(){
    String x = "";
    for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()){  
      x += (m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue()+"\n");
    } return x; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you entered the wrong comparison operator ">" instead of "<". The correct code would be:

```
public Maptester(String[] x){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) map.put(i, x[i]);
}
```